# Prisma, NextJS - Modeling entity types with 1-1 Self-Relationand 1-1 relation to Other entity type

Tags: node.js, next.js, prisma

I am trying to create a model which has a 1-1 self-relation and 1-1 relation with other entity. Here is the code:

```
model Client {
  id String @id @default(uuid())

  name      String
  country   String
  city      String
  taxNumber String
  postcode  Int

  partnerClientId String?      @unique
  partnerClient   Client?      @relation("PartnershipInformation", fields: [partnerClientId], references: [id])
  client          Client?      @relation("PartnershipInformation")
  organizationId  String       @unique
  organization    Organization @relation(fields: [organizationId], references: [id])
}


model Organization {
  id String @id @default(uuid())

  name             String
  type             String
  registrationDate DateTime

  Client           Client?
}
```

And here is how I am inserting the data - because `client` can, but doesn't have to have a `partnerClient`, I have an `if` condition which checks if `partnerClientId` has been supplied to request body:

```
    if (req.body[i].partnerClientId !== '')
        client = await prisma.client.create({
          data: {
            name: req.body[i].name,
            country: req.body[i].country,
            city: req.body[i].city,
            taxNumber: req.body[i].taxNumber,
            postcode: req.body[i].postcode,
            partnerClient: {
              connect: {
                id: req.body[i].partnerClientId
              }
            },
            organization: {
              connect: {
                id: req.body[i].organizationId
              }
            }
          }
        })
      else
        client = await prisma.client.create({
          data: {
            name: req.body[i].name,
            country: req.body[i].country,
            city: req.body[i].city,
            taxNumber: req.body[i].taxNumber,
            postcode: req.body[i].postcode,
            organization: {
              connect: {
                id: req.body[i].organizationId
              }
            }
          }
        })
```

Inserting clients WITHOUT self-reltion works. For example:

```
{
    "name": "Client 1",
    "country": "Country 1",
    "city": "City 1",
    "taxNumber": "12345",
    "postcode": 11111,
    "partnerClientId": "",
    "organizationId": "{EXISTING_UUID}"
},
```

But, as soon as I try to insert something as follows:

```
{
    "name": "Client 3 (self-relation)",
    "country": "Country 3",
    "city": "City 3",
    "taxNumber": "11111",
    "postcode": 22222,
    "partnerClientId": "{CLIENT1_UUID}",
    "organizationId": "{EXISTING_UUID}"
}
```

I get following error:

```
{"level":"error","message":"Error occurred while trying to create a new client -> Error: \nInvalid `prisma.client.create()` invocation in\n/home/stefan/Desktop/Automators/azure-tutorial/dist/Client/index.js:74:50\n\n  71 for (let i = 0; i < req.body.length; i++) {\n  72     var client = null;\n  73     if (req.body[i].partnerClientId !== '')\n→ 74         client = yield prisma.client.create(\nThe change you are trying to make would violate the required relation 'ClientToOrganization' between the `Client` and `Organization` models.","timestamp":"2022-10-30T22:08:16.693Z"}
```

How do I model my DB to enable 1-1 self-relation and 1-1 relation with other entities?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the schema file, I tried creating a client without a partnerClient connected and with a partnerClient connected and both of them worked as expected for me.

```js
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient({
  log: [{ level: 'query', emit: 'stdout' }],
});

async function main() {
  await prisma.client.deleteMany();
  await prisma.organization.deleteMany();

  await prisma.client.create({
    data: {
      id: '1',
      name: 'client1',
      city: 'city1',
      country: 'country1',
      postcode: 12345,
      taxNumber: 'taxNumber1',
      organization: {
        create: {
          id: '1',
          name: 'org1',
          registrationDate: new Date(),
          type: 'type1',
        },
      },
    },
  });

  await prisma.client.create({
    data: {
      id: '2',
      name: 'client2',
      city: 'city2',
      country: 'country2',
      postcode: 54321,
      taxNumber: 'taxNumber2',
      partnerClient: {
        connect: {
          id: '1',
        },
      },
      organization: {
        create: {
          name: 'org2',
          registrationDate: new Date(),
          type: 'type2',
        },
      },
    },
  });
}

main()
  .catch((e) => {
    throw e;
  })
  .finally(async () => {
    await prisma.$disconnect();
  });
```

Here's a sample response which shows connected records.

[image]